# How to connect to a LibreOffice database using PHP

Tags: php, database, pdo, libreoffice

I want to write single-use PHP code that will transfer all of the records in my LibreOffice database table to a MySQL db table. My problem is that I can't work out how to connect to the LOB db using PDO. This is the code that connects to my MySQL database.

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$db = "asoiaf";
$table = "charlist";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $fail) {
    echo $e->getmessage();
}
?>
```

How can I modify this code to connect to the LO database, using PDO? It's called ASOIAF.odb, and the table is - inventively - called CharList. I really don't care if the solution is elegant or follows good practices; it's only for me, so efficacy > efficiency.

Comment: LibreOffice uses HSQLDB, a database server written in Java. There's no native PDO driver for that. You need to get [LibreOffice Base into server mode](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=17567#p162653) and utilze ODBC.

Comment: That sounds complicated for a noob like me. Is there no solution using PHP or some other language? Or a nice step-by-step guide on running LOB in server mode and using ODBC to connect? Or a kind SO user willing to give me a start? :)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/puno/

Comment: Okay, I need to learn how to use an API.